# InfoPath Form calls User Profile Service Log ID:5566 : 401 Unauthorized

Tags: infopath, web-services

I am trying to call UserProfile Service from Infopath 2010 to poulate user details on Form Load.

I get the following error in browser

> An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service. An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5566

Checking ULS logs I get the following error

> Data adapter failed during OnLoad: The remote server returned an error: (401)

Please help me on this

Comment: Did you follow any specific blog or article when setting up the connection to the user profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the issue is.

1. Install [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2516485) (you may already have this hotfix in your farm) on all WFEs.
   This is necessary so that the “userName()” function in InfoPath will
   return a result in domain\username format, instead of just username.
2. In SharePoint Central Administration, create a new “Group” Secure
   Store App, assign “All Authenticated Users” as the membership
   condition, and set the credentials to a user with permissions to
   access user information for all site users (i.e. a site admin).
3. In the UDCX file for the data connection calling the
   “GetUserProfileByName” web service method, add the Secure Store App
   information and reapprove:

   ```
   <udc:Authentication>
       <udc:SSO AppId="GetUserProfileByNameSSA" CredentialType="NTLM" />
   </udc:Authentication>
   ```
4. In the form template, in design mode, modify the
   “GetUserProfileByName” data connection so it does not initialize on
   load.
5. In the “Form Load” rule, add actions to set the “AccountName” query
   field of the “GetUserProfileByName” data connection to the
   “userName()” function, and then query the data connection.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/saantil/archive/2013/03/29/an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-connect-to-a-web-service.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/544a81dc-214a-4caf-aa42-fc9dec796882/webservice-call-fails-from-infopath-webbased-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy